# issue with dpkg when trying --fix-broken with apt

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dpkg

I am trying to fix some issues with broken libs after failed to install another package. I ran `sudo apt --fix-broken install` and it failed with this result:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libglx-dev_1.3.2-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/GL/glx.h', which is also in package mesa-common-dev:amd64 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~18.04.1
Preparing to unpack .../libgl-dev_1.3.2-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgl-dev:amd64 (1.3.2-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgl-dev_1.3.2-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/GL/gl.h', which is also in package mesa-common-dev:amd64 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~18.04.1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../libegl-dev_1.3.2-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libegl-dev:amd64 (1.3.2-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libegl-dev_1.3.2-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/EGL/egl.h', which is also in package libegl1-mesa-dev:amd64 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~18.04.1
Preparing to unpack .../libgles-dev_1.3.2-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgles-dev:amd64 (1.3.2-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgles-dev_1.3.2-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/GLES2/gl2.h', which is also in package libgles2-mesa-dev:amd64 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~18.04.1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libglx-dev_1.3.2-1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgl-dev_1.3.2-1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libegl-dev_1.3.2-1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgles-dev_1.3.2-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I can not run some applications that require gtk due to that series of libs being broken.

Any suggestions for a fix?

`uname -a`

```
Linux ubuntu 5.4.0-84-generic #94~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 26 23:17:46 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this.

I had to remove some packages with dpkg

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq libgtk-3-dev
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq mesa-common-dev
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq libegl1-mesa-dev
sudo dpkg --remove libgles2-mesa-dev
```

Then I ran `sudo apt --fix-broken install`

I had to also run all updates and upgrades to fix everything.